# Detecting movement using acclerometer in phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, accelerometer, phonegap

I was making an app so I wanted to use the accelerometer to detect if the user has moved the device so I wanted to know how can I include the accelerometer plugin into a PhoneGap build app by adding it into the config.xml file and how can I check the device movement in the app after every 20 - 30 ms using javascript?

Answer (score 2):

Cordova
To install the plugin in your Cordova app, run the following:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device-motion
```

PhoneGap
To add the plugin to your PhoneGap app, add the following to your config.xml:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-motion" />
```

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Acceleration Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-x.x.x.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // The watch id references the current `watchAcceleration`
    var watchID = null;

    // Wait for Cordova to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        startWatch();
    }

    // Start watching the acceleration
    //
    function startWatch() {

        // Update acceleration every 3 seconds
        var options = { frequency: 30 };

        watchID = navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(onSuccess, onError, options);
    }

    // Stop watching the acceleration
    //
    function stopWatch() {
        if (watchID) {
            navigator.accelerometer.clearWatch(watchID);
            watchID = null;
        }
    }

    // onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current acceleration
    //
    function onSuccess(acceleration) {
        var element = document.getElementById('accelerometer');
        element.innerHTML = 'Acceleration X: ' + acceleration.x + '<br />' +
                            'Acceleration Y: ' + acceleration.y + '<br />' +
                            'Acceleration Z: ' + acceleration.z + '<br />' +
                            'Timestamp: '      + acceleration.timestamp + '<br />';
    }

    // onError: Failed to get the acceleration
    //
    function onError() {
        alert('onError!');
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="accelerometer">Waiting for accelerometer...</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried your way but it is not working and when I build it white PhoneGap build and installed the app then it just shows "Waiting for accelerometer....." is it related to apk signing or something

Comment: be sure cordova.js is valid. you need to build your phone first and if you want to add button for get acceleration add to js function getAcceleration(){
        navigator.accelerometer.getCurrentAcceleration(onAccelSuccess, onError);
    } and add  <p>
        <button onclick="getAcceleration()">Get Acceleration</button>
    </p> to body